# using .htacces to rewrite URLs with query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess, query-string

I have a page which is www.example.com/page_name.php?var1=dynamic_var1&var2=dynamic_var2

I want to use .htaccess file to make it look like this
www.example.com/page_name/dynamic_var1/dynamic_var2

I have tried this so far

```
RewriteRule ^page_name/(.*)/(.*)$ page_name.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC]
```

and the problem is when this is going to database it goes like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=dynamic_var1/dynamic_var2.php/dynamic_var1 LIMIT 1
```

and i also tried this

```
RewriteRule page_name/(\w+)/(\w+) page_name.php?var=$1&var2=$2
```

it is loading the page but without any pictures or css file or anything, and when i used firebug it said that it failed to load the URL given.

and when i tried this

```
RewriteRule ^page_name/(\w+)/(\w+)$ page_name.php?var=$1&var2=$2
```

It gave me internal server error

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try split the URL from within the `.htaccess` file.  Why don't you try simply passing the entire query string to your `index.php` or any other script you want and parse the request there...

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

A much easier way would be to simply redirect all the requests into an `index.php` file that does something like this -

`index.php` -

Given `http://yourdomain.com/user/123`

```
$originalURL = $_GET['url'];
$URLParts = explode('/',$originalURL);
```

Now you have inside of `$URLParts`

```
Array (
 'user',
 '123'
)
```

Now you can easily place these values in your SQL query.

**Watch out** for SQL injection though!  always use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and make sure to sanitize any incoming data...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer you really saved the day, only 9 mins left to accept the answer